# How do I add web-interface functions to my Swift WebView

Tags: swift, server, wkwebview

Android's [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) affords me the opportunity to add functions that can be called directly from the server. For instance, I can write a function `displayToast(message)` this way:

```
...
// add webapp interface to webview
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");

// Web app interface
public class WebAppInterface {

    // Javascript interface function to display a toast
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void displayToast(String message) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I can then call `Android.displayToast()` in my Javascript code (as in the code snippet below) and then have a toast message displayed on the user's screen.

```
const performOperation = () => {
    ...
    Android.displayToast("The process was successful")
}
```

I want to implement something exactly like this in a native iOs codebase using Swift. **I want to include functions in my Swift [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) that I can call directly from the server.** How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by injecting javascript code into the webview.

Let's say for example we want to get the print of `console.log` in our application to display it in our application.

From javascript if you want to send a message to the webkit you must use this `window.webkit.messageHandlers.{NAME_TO_IDENTIFY_RECEVEID_MESSAGE}.postMessage({MESSAGE_TO_SEND})`

For example `window.webkit.messageHandlers.logging.postMessage(MyLog)`

You must register this type to the webview:

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "logging")
```

Messages are received in the delegate of `WKScriptMessageHandler`:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        let type = message.name
        let message = message.body

        print("Received message: \(message) from \(type)")
        // Output Received message: MyLog from logging
    }
```

If you have access to the server code you can simply add the code below to override the log function which will send the messages to the webkit:

```
var console = { log: function(msg){window.webkit.messageHandlers.logging.postMessage(msg) } };
```

If you don't have access to the server you can inject the javascript code from the webview like this (declared before `webView.load (request)`):

```
let scriptJS = "var console = { log: function(msg){window.webkit.messageHandlers.logging.postMessage(msg) } };"
let logScript = WKUserScript(source: scriptJS, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)

 webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(logScript)
```

So here I explained to you how it works here, we taken the example of handle the `console.log`.

The most important thing to remember is that you can send messages via `window.webkit.messageHandlers.{NAME_TO_IDENTIFY_RECEVEID_MESSAGE}.postMessage({MESSAGE_TO_SEND})`

and handle it here `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)`

Comment: Wow, awesome! I can also use this logic to add more functions, right? For instance, I would also like to add a function that returns the user's contacts. Can I have  a func `getContacts()` and then call it directly from the server like that (PS: I have access to the server code).

Comment: Yes it remains in the same logic you must send a message to your webview to tell him to retrieve the contacts, after you have retrieved the contacts you can send them to an API. If my response helped you mark as resolved

Comment: I actually want to avoid using APIs. While implementing this on Android, I didn't have to use APIs. I relied entirely on my function's return value as well as its parameters. For instance, to send a list of contacts, all my function needs to do is to return a JSONArray; I just decouple into a normal list in the server code. You understand? By the way, thanks +1.

Comment: If you want to send the contacts without api directly to the webview you can do it, after having retrieved the contacts you can inject them into the webview using the `evaluateJavaScript ()` function. So if in your server you have a function that receives an array or jsonObject array as a parameter, you can transmit it. Lookt at this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-run-javascript-on-a-wkwebview-with-evaluatejavascript